# Torch multi-processing on single GPU is extremely slow

Tags: multiprocessing, gpu, pytorch

I have a torch code in which I am trying to calculate the output of 10 layers that are independent of each other. It seems like a case where torch multi-processing fits perfectly. Here is the code for that replicates the situation in my case:

```
from torch.multiprocessing import Pool, set_start_method
import torch
from torch.autograd import Variable

from kernel_2_0 import *
from kernel_2_1 import *
from kernel_2_2 import *
from kernel_2_3 import *
from kernel_2_4 import *
from kernel_2_5 import *
from kernel_2_6 import *
from kernel_2_7 import *
from kernel_2_8 import *
from kernel_2_9 import *

def apply_fn(args):
    f = args[0]
    x = args[1]
    return f(x)

def forward_2(x):
    assert isinstance(x.data, torch.cuda.BoolTensor)
    try:
        set_start_method('spawn', force=True)
    except RuntimeError:
        print('Could not set spawn method')
    with Pool(12) as pool:
        mapped_out = pool.map(apply_fn,
                              [(kernel_2_0, x), (kernel_2_1, x), (kernel_2_2, x), (kernel_2_3, x), (kernel_2_4, x),
                               (kernel_2_5, x), (kernel_2_6, x), (kernel_2_7, x), (kernel_2_8, x), (kernel_2_9, x)])

out = Variable(torch.cuda.BoolTensor(x.size()[0], 10))
out[:, 0] = mapped_out[0]
out[:, 1] = mapped_out[1]
out[:, 2] = mapped_out[2]
out[:, 3] = mapped_out[3]
out[:, 4] = mapped_out[4]
out[:, 5] = mapped_out[5]
out[:, 6] = mapped_out[6]
out[:, 7] = mapped_out[7]
out[:, 8] = mapped_out[8]
out[:, 9] = mapped_out[9]

return out
```

However, when the code runs it is almost 100 times slower than the version where I do not do multi processing an instead call all the kernels in a sequential manner. FYI I am using `torch==1.4.0` and `cuda-10.0`. I am not able to understand why this happens. Can someone please help? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you aware that pytorch already uses [asynchronous execution](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/cuda.html#asynchronous-execution) for cuda tensors?

Comment: @jodag Thank you for pointing this out. I did not know this. I read the document and it seems that it is talking about the case where there are multiple Pytorch scripts issuing kernel calls on a single GPU. However, I want to be able to call multiple functions in an asynchronous manner from the same script. It'd be great if you could help me figure out the solution. Thank you!

Comment: Hi @HitarthKanakiya, have you solved this? I have the same problem and I can't figure out what's going on.